# Как сделать,чтобы при закрытии приложения компьютер выключался?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Сейчас делаю свою первую программу типа родительского контроля и мне нужно,чтобы при закрытии окна компьютер выключался

Comment: Какую ОС вы используете?

Answer (score 1):

Используя модуль [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) можно взаимодействовать с различными командами операционной системы, в данном случае нам понадобиться метод [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system).

Стоит учитывать, что для разных операционных систем используются разные команды для выключения.

Для Windows:

```
import os

os.system("shutdown /s /t 0")
```

Для Linux:

```
import os

#Для Linux необходимы соответствующие права через sudo
os.system("sudo shutdown now")
```

---

Предположим ситуацию, в которой мы бы хотели иметь универсальную процедуру для отключения любого компьютера, в таком случае нам нужно определять операционную систему и отправлять определенную команду операционной системы для каждого. Для этого мы можем использовать модуль `platform`. Для получения контекста операционной системы используется инструкция [`platform.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#:%7E:text=platform.system,cannot%20be%20determined.).

Можно реализовать это таким образом:

```
import os
import platform

def shutdown_computer():
    current_os = platform.system()

    if current_os == "Windows":
        os.system("shutdown /s /t 0")
    elif current_os == "Linux":
        os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
    else:
        print("Невозможно определить операционную систему или не поддерживается.")

# Вызов процедуры выключения компьютера
shutdown_computer()
```

Блок условий в данном коде нуждается в дополнении, так как он не учитывает контекста всех операционных систем.